# Find min max average , 75 and 95 quantile over a group of columns rather than column by column

Tags: python, pandas

Each column in my pandas data frame represents a time series. I can find the min max, means and different quantiles column by column without an issue. For some analysis I need to find the overall min , max , average , and different quantiles over the entire dataframe. For example if the data frame is as below

```
  a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Then I need the min , max , average , 75 and 95 quantile of the values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `Series` from all columns by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) or [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then processing:

```
s = df.stack()
print (s)
0  a    1
   b    2
   c    3
1  a    4
   b    5
   c    6
2  a    7
   b    8
   c    9
dtype: int64
```

```
s = df.melt()['value']
print (s)
0    1
1    4
2    7
3    2
4    5
5    8
6    3
7    6
8    9
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (s.describe(percentiles=[.75,.95]))
count    9.000000
mean     5.000000
std      2.738613
min      1.000000
50%      5.000000
75%      7.000000
95%      8.600000
max      9.000000
dtype: float64
```